# Is the tetrahedron necessarily mirror-asymmetric?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was shocked to watch Anton Petrov's latest video, ["Wow, Incredible Evidence That Universe Is Not Symmetric After All"](https://youtu.be/d15b7udf_ac), where he says that the Tetrahedron is the simplest object that is not Z(2)-symmetric.

Does this mean that you can't connect four equilateral triangles to form a symmetric polyhedron, or is Anton wrong?

ty.

Comment: I don't have the time to look through that video, but surely a regular tetrahedron has reflections as symmetries. If you look at [the animation to show its order two rotational symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1704734/11619) you will see that it also has as a symmetry the reflection w.r.t. the plane intersecting the surrounding cube along the diagonal of the top face and perpendicular to it.

Comment: So Anton is wrong. that's what I thought. Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, I withdraw the question, your honor. Does deleting a question have a negative impact on your number of points, or whatever you call it? Normally I wouldn't care, but as a brand new user, I don't yet have enough point to do some things.

Comment: Saying that the tetrahedron is not $Z(2)$ symmetric can probably mean that the tetrahedron is not centrally symmetric, which is well known.

Comment: There is no such a thing as **the** tetrahedron. Some tetrahedra are symmetric, some are not.